# i have a problem when i try to use useReducer hooks in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

this is my code

```js
import React, {createContext, useContext, useReducer } from 'react';

// this is data layer
export const StateContext = createContext();

//  build a provider
export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children}) => {
    
    <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
        {children}
    </StateContext.Provider>
};
```

but when i run the app i get this error

Failed to compile.

./src/StateProvider.js
Line 9:5:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're not returning from `StateProvider` functional component.
Replace your `StateProvider` declaration with

```
    export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children}) => (
        <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
            {children}
        </StateContext.Provider>
    )
```

(notice `{ }` replaced with `( )`)

Or

```
    export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children}) => {
        return (
            <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
                {children}
            </StateContext.Provider>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`<StateProvider />` is not a valid React Component because it's not returning any React Element. It's all about JSX, and arrow function stuffs. The error message also gives you this hint.

```js
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => { statements } 
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => expression
// equivalent to: => { return expression; }

// Parenthesize the body of a function to return an object literal expression:
params => ({foo: bar})
```

- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

In your case, `StateProvider` is returning nothing.

Make it:

```js
export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children}) => (
        <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
            {children}
        </StateContext.Provider>
)
```